# Acronis Cloning of Redhat Linux Server

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, disk-image, acronis

I tried to evaluate Acronis Backup & Recovery 11 for my redhat linux before deciding what cloning software to purchase for my company, but doesn't seem to get it working.

My redhat linux box has the following filesystems:

```
- /dev/sda1                         (mounted on "/boot")
- /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00   (mounted on "/")
- /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01   (Linux swap space)
```

I selected all the above filesystem for backup and used 'Fast Cataloging' under the Acronis' Backup Options. But encountered 'Cataloging data' has failed errors as follows:

```
--------------------
Log Entry Details
--------------------
Type:          Error
Date and time: 4/11/12 5:25:09 PM
Backup plan:   Backup 4/11/12 5:07:58 PM
Task:          Simple backup
Code:          20,250,685(0x135003D)
Module:        309
Owner:         root
Message:       
  Command 'Cataloging data' has failed.
Additional info: 
--------------------
Error code: 61
Module: 309
LineInfo: 4a8728dc8a1c94f4
Fields:  $module : service_process_lxa64
Message: Command 'Cataloging data' has failed.
--------------------
Error code: 13
Module: 388
LineInfo: 6bbbd9081b12e591
Fields:  $module : gtob_indexer_commands_addon_lxa64_pic
Message: 
--------------------
Error code: 2
Module: 388
LineInfo: 6bbbd9081b12e58a
Fields:  $module : gtob_indexer_commands_addon_lxa64_pic
Message: Failed to open SQLite database file 'sdb1:/dw4/Catalog/3FC5014F-5689-41E7-B49E-F078B442E0A3/catalog.db'.
--------------------
Error code: 2
Module: 388
LineInfo: ad9452270c4f4b09
Fields:  $module : gtob_indexer_commands_addon_lxa64_pic
Message: Failed to open SQLite database file 'sdb1:/dw4/Catalog/3FC5014F-5689-41E7-B49E-F078B442E0A3/catalog.db'.
--------------------
Error code: 13
Module: 441
LineInfo: b35458cf679ba63f
Fields:  $module : gtob_indexer_commands_addon_lxa64_pic
Message: 
--------------------
Acronis Knowledge Base: http://kb.acronis.com/errorcode/

Event code: 0x0135003D+0x0184000D+0x01840002+0x01840002+0x01B9000D

--------------------
```

Does anyone encounter the above errors? Or I can ignore these errors as there are TIB files generated?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, native linux tools `dump` and `restore` are preferrable. They do all the same as Acronis. The only difference is that you have to create partitions and filesystems on a target disk before restoring.